# General purpose network manager in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http, networking

I'm working on an Android project (API level 10) which needs to send and receive http messages to/from a server.

I implemented a class named NetworkManager which provides different methods, one for each http request (e.g.: loginRequest(user pass), RegistrationRequest(user.....) ).

All these methods generates a JSON object that is passed to the method called sendMessage, which is the method that actually establish the connection, sends and receives the response (also a json object).

Of course network calls are time consuming, so i first decided to use an AsyncTask to display a progressDialog while the network operation is being performed.

The problem is that i need to get the response value retrived from the background thread before executing any other operation which involves the result itself done by the Main thread.
At the same time i would like to make a common and reusable implementation of the AsyncTask.

E.g.: I have a login activity which shows 2 EditText (username, password) and a button called Login. When I press the login button, a progressDialog must appear, and must be disposed once the doInBackground task is accomplished. Of course i could do this way:

```
onClick(View v) //called when the login button is pressed
{
    onPreExecute()
    {
        //Show the progress dialog
    }

    doInBackground()
    {
        //Retreive the login response (an integer containing a message code) using sendLoginRequest(username, password);
        //return the response
    }

    onPostExecute(int response)
    {
        //Dispose the progress dialog, then loginSucessfull ? start new activity : show error toast
    }
}
```

But, doing this way i should implement an async task for every request i need to send which is what i would like to avoid because if i have N requests i should create N classes that extend AsyncTask.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i would suggest you is to use **INTERFACES** for handling response of http request.

The background thread either it be a AysncTask or it be Thread needs to handle both

- response
- exception

Think it like this way

**MainThread** - Hey Background Thread do this operation and let me know when you are done.

**MainThread** - Ok till Background Thread executes its operation let me show progress dialog.

**BackGroundThread** - I am done with my work. hey MainThread here catch you response or exception

**MainThread** - Let me stop showing progress bar.

So we need to simulate this callback mechanism via code and also needs to take care that we implement a reusable architecture.

Something like this

Define a Interface

```
public interface HttpRequestResponse {
    public void onSuccess(HttpResponse response);
    public void onException(Exception exception); 
}     


class HttpRequestResponseHandler {

   private ActionItem action;
   private HttpRequestResponse hrr;
   private Executor executor; 

   public enum ActionItem {
      LOGIN_REQUEST ,
      REGISTRATION_REQUEST            
   } 

   public HttpRequestResponseHandler(ActionItem action, HttpRequestResponse hrr) {
      this.action = action;
      this.hrr = hrr;       
   }

   public void execute(){
     executor = new Executor();
     executor.execute();       
   }

   private class Executor extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

      @Override
      public Void doInBackground() {
         switch(action) {

            case LOGIN_REQUEST : doLogin();
                                 break;   

            case REGISTRATION_REQUEST : doRegistration();
                                        break; 
         }
      }
   }

   private void doLogin() {

      HttpResponse response = null;
      Exception exception = null;
      try {
         response = makeHttpRequestHere();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         exception = e;
      }

      if(exception != null) {
         hrr.onException(exception);
      } else {
         hrr.onSuccess(response);
      }

   }   

}
```

Now in somewhere in your activity code file do like this.

```
 HttpRequestResponse hrr = new HttpRequestResponse(){

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(HttpResponse response) {
       hideProgressDialog();
       handleResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Exception exception) {
       hideProgressDialog();
       showErrorDialog(exception.getMessage());
    } 
 }

 HttpRequestResponseHandler hrrh = new HttpRequestResponseHandler(ActionItem.LOGIN_REQUEST,hrr);
 hrrh.execute();
 showProgressDialog();
```

Hope all this lead to what you want. 
Its been a long answer and took quite a effort of mine to figure. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, very clear! With little modifications i managed to reuse your code into my project ;-)

Comment: If it helps accept the answer by clicking green right symbol given on the left side of the answer. This way you appreciate answer and helps other leading in the right direction. This way this community works. :)

Answer (score 0):

why not just using AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR(Runnable run);

It wraps a thread pool based executor of #cores + 1 parallelity level.

Then you can simply invoke:

```
AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
       doLogin();
});
```